# Wordpress URL mask

Tags: wordpress, redirect, affiliate

On my website I have implemented PP, links are generated using the plugin, they look like this:

http://mojadomena.pl/offer/random-number (with each refreshed link random number changes)

Links go through redirection 302 to partner pages. I would like to change this and hide the links to PP ie when the user clicks on the link, it will redirect it to the LP, and the LP will automatically get the redirected JS to the landing page (partner), if it is possible to do so, if so, I count on the small tips wink .gif

The redirect has Ceneo:

When we click "Go to store" eg https://www.ceneo.pl/Click/Offer/?e=oNK_F-8BBpZIzCVw6veaXzfLgdFGaMD982IhOZzCHZdYrPbMYaqitGCFOfn1whB9tutvD22rmNLtDXZLXRtxo_gVczVHv790mYbWJMNsG47xaNEx0jm6tH8ZrJQZKXK63piwD5UIsOzratHqzSCpru9HMNOMmdfrMGWs7wxccoGVaDxUO50zBOCyMUinnJQ3cbHG4F53rBy3Ax5fwLervfxnnPuqQBXlTMMnmxAC39_UEh8tmFuRNpjbFq2fuWcrQivg1JLkFehPOFQcDx7xnqhl3-TzZ3XO6rKcrinouv9FpNFgCkXi5h_TLcO8eMoQpVBMwlkFDd0rPU-afU4aAv_F5Wh_f6kjW5VAEOgglFalUEzCWQUN3UJ8qwMgyOsBq-GnDCPtcf_poyrTKmZKQGX4vGZh30svoIlDlZR4T6g%3d

And there is a redirect to JS, all you can see in the Web Sniffer.

Comment: What does PP mean?

Comment: Partner Program.